# Python Polars: How to apply a aggregate function for all columns and pass one additional column as argument?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a lazy dataframe (using `scan_parquet`) like below,

```py
region   time  sen1   sen2   sen3
us       1     10.0   11.0   12.0
us       2     11.0   14.0   13.0
us       3     10.1   10.0   12.3
us       4     13.0   11.1   14.0
us       5     12.0   11.0   19.0
uk       1     10.0   11.0   12.1
uk       2     11.0   14.0   13.0
uk       3     10.1   10.0   12.0
uk       4     13.0   11.1   14.0
uk       5     12.0   11.0   19.0
uk       6     13.7   11.1   14.0
uk       7     12.0   11.0   21.9
```

I want to find max and min for all the sensors for each region and while doing so, I also wanted the time at which max and min happened.

So, I wrote the below aggregate function,

```
def my_custom_agg(t,v):
   smax = v.max()
   smin = v.min()
   smax_t = t[v.arg_max()]
   smin_t = t[v.arg_max()]
   return [smax, smin, smax_t, smin_t]
```

Then I did the groupby as below,

```
df.groupby('region').agg(
   [
      pl.col('*').apply(lambda s: my_custom_agg(pl.col('time'),s))
   ]
)
```

When I do this, I get the below error,

```
TypeError: 'Expr' object is not subscribable
```

Expected result,

```
region sen1              sen2              sen3
us     [13.0,10.0,4,1]   [14.0,10.0,2,3]   [19.0,12.0,5,1]
uk     [13.7,10.0,6,1]   [14.0,10.0,2,3]   [21.9,12.0,7,3]

# which I will melt and transform to below,
region   sname  smax  smin smax_t  smin_t
us       sen1   13.0  10.0 4       1
us       sen2   14.0  10.0 2       3
us       sen3   19.0  12.0 5       1
uk       sen1   13.7  10.0 6       1
uk       sen2   14.0  10.0 2       3
uk       sen3   21.9  12.0 7       3
```

Could you please tell me how to pass one additional column as an argument? If there is an alternative way to do this, I am happy to hear it since I am flexible with the output format.

Note: In my real dataset I have 8k sensors, so it is better to do with `*`.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You could `.melt()` and `.sort()` first.

Then when you `.groupby()` you can use `.first()` and `.last()` to get the min/max for time and value.

`pl.all()` can be used instead of `pl.col("*")`

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .melt(["region", "time"], variable_name="sname")
...    .sort(pl.all().exclude("time"))
...    .groupby(["region", "sname"])
...    .agg([
...       pl.all().first().suffix("_min"),
...       pl.all().last() .suffix("_max"),
...    ])
... )
shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬───────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ region ┆ sname ┆ time_min ┆ value_min ┆ time_max ┆ value_max │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ str   ┆ i64      ┆ f64       ┆ i64      ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ uk     ┆ sen1  ┆ 1        ┆ 10.0      ┆ 6        ┆ 13.7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ uk     ┆ sen3  ┆ 3        ┆ 12.0      ┆ 7        ┆ 21.9      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ us     ┆ sen1  ┆ 1        ┆ 10.0      ┆ 4        ┆ 13.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ us     ┆ sen2  ┆ 3        ┆ 10.0      ┆ 2        ┆ 14.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ uk     ┆ sen2  ┆ 3        ┆ 10.0      ┆ 2        ┆ 14.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ us     ┆ sen3  ┆ 1        ┆ 12.0      ┆ 5        ┆ 19.0      │
└────────┴───────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @jqurious. It does work however, it slower compared to the custom aggregate function. If I replace the code I shared like this `my_custom_agg(s,s)` although this is not what I wanted, the execution time is 3s but yours take 21s. Is there any other performant way?

Comment: Just a guess, I dont have access to the data, but what if you, after the `melt`, first do the `groupby`, and then inside the `agg` use `pl.all().sort_by("value").first()` & `pl.all().sort_by("value").last()`. That would avoid the `sort` call on the big dataframe, and instead allow to parallelize inside each `groupby` (and with 8K sensors you have a lot of groups).